# Laravel array pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am working on the pagination of the results from the research page. The code has two pages.

1. index page that direct to the page with the search form.
2. the second page is the result page where the output should be displayed. I want the results to be displayed in pages. my code is:
   in the search function the output this is the code

```php
$final_list = $this->paginate($final_list,5);

return view('results',['list' => $final_list]);
```

The paginate function is:

```php
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 5,  $page = null, $options = [])

{

   $page =  $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);

   $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);

   return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, page, 
   $options);

}
```

in the result page I display the data and add the `{!! $list->links()  !!}` to get pages.

The code displays the output for the first page. The issue I am facing is when I click to the second or any other page it direct me to the index page where I have to fill in the search form again before displaying the result of that page.
I don't understand what is wrong in this code. Could you please help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to append your search filter data to your main data array.

**$detail_data->appends(['keyword' => $keyword]);**

I share sample code of controller

```
    $keyword = $request->keyword;
    $deals = Deal::join('category','category.id','=','deals.deal_category_id')
                ->join('users','users.id','=','deals.user_id')
                ->select('deals.*', 'category.cat_name', 'users.name AS username', 'users.profile_photo_path')
                ->where('deal_isApproved', '=', 'Approved');
    $deals->where(function($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('deal_title', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                ->orWhere('category.cat_name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
    });
    $detail_data = $deals->paginate(20);
    $detail_data->appends(['keyword' => $keyword]);
```

I blade template file

```
{{ $detail_data->links() }}
```

Comment: Thank you Harsh, However, I tried this and nothing changed I still go back to the search form after clicking on the next page. Basically I have four collections with data from different queries ($data1, $data2, $data3, and $data4), the $final_list is the merge of those collections and it is the one I want to paginate. I tried the appends(['keyword' => $keyword]); but nothing changed still I am running into the same issue.